# Drupal know from where things are showed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a strange question but I don't find any hint about that (if it's possible), for a drupal 7 website I have to modify some content of a page in the backoffice, but I really don't know from where some content of this page is created (a table, similar to a view table but not a view table).

I just want to know if there is any way to show which php function the page use to finally be showed. I know there is something like that for the theme (drupal theme debug) but I don't find something for my case.

Any idea ?

Comment: You can often get a clue from the classes in the html

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP profiler to check all functions called on page, there's a module for Drupal7 for  [XHProf](https://www.drupal.org/project/xhprof) integration. But I would suggest you to use your browsers inspector as mentioned by 2pha before. For example if there's a form on the page just use the form ID to find it. Custom classes are very useful in these cases, parts of the html codes etc. *In your case search for table headers...*

The code you are looking for is most probably in custom modules and the
general suggestion is to keep you custom modules in separated folder from contributed ones.